# Multiple Atrous Convolutions are slow

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am implementing a layer in torch fusing multiple atrous convolutions much like the Atrous Spatial Pyramid Pooling in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.05587.pdf.

The problem is that adding this layer slows down my training drastically.

The use of multiple dilated (atrous) convolutions drops my gpu utilization from 90% to 30% for some reason.

When I removed the dilated (atrous) convolutions or used just one of them and repeatedly appended it, there wasn't an issue. Are there any suggestions about the possible bottleneck existing in my code below?

The shape of x in the code below is `(batch_size, 1024, 16, 16)`

```
class MultiAtrous(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dilated_conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            1024, 512, kernel_size=3, dilation=3, padding=3)
        self.dilated_conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            1024, 512, kernel_size=3, dilation=6, padding=6)
        self.dilated_conv3 = nn.Conv2d(
            1024, 512, kernel_size=3, dilation=9, padding=9)
        self.conv1x1 = nn.Conv2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=1)
        self.gap = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.upsample = nn.Upsample(size=(16,16), mode='bilinear')

    def forward(self, x):
        local_feat = []
        local_feat.append(self.dilated_conv1(x))
        local_feat.append(self.dilated_conv2(x))
        local_feat.append(self.dilated_conv3(x))
        local_feat.append(self.upsample(self.relu(self.conv1x1(self.gap(x)))))
        local_feat = torch.cat(local_feat, dim=1)
        return local_feat
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [`torch.profiler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/profiler.html?highlight=profiler#module-torch.profiler) to spot the bottleneck?

Comment: I will try doing so.

Comment: *The use of multiple dilated (atrous) convolutions drops my gpu utilization from 90% to 30% for some reason. When I removed the dilated (atrous) convolutions or used just one of them and repeatedly appended it, there wasn't an issue*. The two sentences seem contradictory. Using multiple convs improves or worsens speed performance?

Comment: Multiple convs worsens the performance

Comment: Your channel dimensions are quite high, I wouldn't be surprised to find that to be the reason for the speed change. What are the inputs shapes of your layer?

Comment: The shapes are (batch_size, 1024, 16, 16). I have currently replaced this layer with Lite Reduced Atrous Spatial Pyramid Pooling (LR-ASPP) from mobilenetv3, which is supposed to be a lighter version that replaces the three atrous convolutions with a single 1x1 convolution. I would like to know the reason behind the bottleneck though.

Comment: Could you please provide the implementation version you compared your speed perf with (the one with *just one of them and repeatedly appended it*) by editing the question above?

Comment: local_feat = []
        y = self.dilated_conv1(x)
        local_feat.append(y)
        local_feat.append(y)
        local_feat.append(y)
        local_feat.append(self.upsample(self.relu(self.conv1x1(self.gap(x)))))
        local_feat = torch.cat(local_feat, dim=1)
        return local_feat

Comment: Seems logical to me that you would have a speed overhead when applying three convolutions vs only one. Did you profile/time the speed difference?

Comment: @Ivan But it seems weird that these two convolutions make such a big difference when the rest of the model has like 60million parameters